# Rails. Sum a specific attribute on a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of invoices...

```
@invoices_1_week = Invoice.order("due_date DESC").where("status != 'paid' AND due_date >= ? AND due_date < ?", Date.today, 1.week.from_now)
```

The invoices model has a total attribute. How can I get a sum of the totals in the @invoice_1_week collection?

I know I can do it in the view like this...

```
<% week_1_total = 0 %>
<% @invoices_1_week.each do |invoice| %>
  <% week_1_total = week_1_total + invoice.total %>
<% end %>
<%= week_1_total %>
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more Railsy way of doing it.

Comment: you should never write code like this in a view, move any logic to helper or models (depending on its nature).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a Rails way, using ActiveRecord's `sum` method:

```
@invoices_1_week.sum("total")
```

[Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) are the docs.

Comment: How do you allow for NIL or NULL values in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the symbol notation

```
@invoices_1_week.sum(:total)
```

or use single quotes

```
@invoices_1_week.sum('total')
```

In both cases, the attribute name is immutable.